# Stop List running Ruby Terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal

I'm running some tutorial and github ruby programs as I learn. When I run one of the programs in terminal, it asks me to enter some things, one per line. I know this is silly but how do I tell it I'm done entering things in terminal?

```
puts "Please input a list of stocks, one per line"
LifeCycleReportItem.setup
report = Report.new
tickers = Array.new
STDIN.readlines.each { | ticker |
  tickers.push(ticker.chomp)
}
```

Here's terminal:

```
Please input a list of stocks, one per line
GOOG
AAPL
```

How do I tell it I'm done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to write an EOF (or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows).

If this software is meant to be easy/used by humans, though, you might consider saying "or a blank line to stop" and checking for that instead. (It won't work using `STDIN.readlines.each`, though - just `gets` instead `:)`)

Comment: yeah, not my code, just figured out how to stop it asking me for more lines :)

Answer (score 2):

You could handle a stop string. For example, when ticker is an empty string:

```
while(ticker = STDIN.gets.chomp) do
  break if ticker.empty?

  tickers.push(ticker)
end
```

Comment: With `STDIN.readlines.each`, the block won't even be executed until it gets an EOF, though.